# What is this setup called?

Tags: transistors

What is the T1 and T2 setup called?

[image: Schematic]

I'm sorry if the question is vague because that's how it was presented in the exercise

Comment: I think this position is vacant. Call it whatever you want.

Comment: Looks like a cascode amplifier?

Comment: That's a "cascode" arrangement. T2 base is held at constant voltage and emitter is driven. Much on web under that name.

Comment: Invented in 1939 using triode vacuum tubes. I used it long ago (1960s) as an RF front end for a US WW2 surplus ARC5 receiver with surprisingly good effect.

Comment: @EugeneSh. As it was first named "Cascode" in 1939 calling it anything else may cause complaint :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

traditionally it would be called a Common Source JFET driver to a Common Base (wide BW) NPN amplifier.

The vertical configuration is also a cascode..

It is “open loop” and may be improved with negative feedback for linearity.